# How to make the global value reset each time?

Tags: python-3.x

```
def playAgain():
    b = input('Do you want to play again? y/n')
    if b == ('y'):
        def startGame():
            startGame()
    else:
        print('Goodbye!')
        time.sleep(1)
        sys.exit()
import random
import time
import sys

global shots
shots = 0


while shots <=5:
    chanceofDeath =random.randint(1,6)
    input('press enter to play Russian roulette.')
    if chanceofDeath ==1:
        shots = shots + 1
        print (shots)
        print('You died.')
        time.sleep(1)
        playAgain()
    else:
        shots = shots + 1
        print (shots)
        print ('click')


    if shots == 5:
        print('You won without dying!')
        time.sleep(1)
        playAgain()
```

When I run the program, when it asks to play again or not, if you choose yes it works, but continues from the last shot. For example, if you died on the second shot and played again, instead of restarting, it starts right off at 3. How do I make the shots reset everytime?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why it continues from the last shot is because you never actually set the 'shots' back to 0 this code:

```
import random
import time
import sys

global shots
shots = 0
```

is ran only once, meaning shots is never assigned back to 0.

---

What you want is if the user chooses to play again, the 'shots' variable should be set back to 0. You could edit your playAgain() function to return True if the user wanted to play again. For example:

```
def playAgain():
    b = input('Do you want to play again? y/n')
    if b == ('y'):
        return True
    else:
        print('Goodbye!')
        time.sleep(1)
        sys.exit()
```

This allows you to check for whether the user wanted to play again in your main while loop and set 'shots' to 0 like this:

```
if playAgain():
    shots = 0
```

Also as shots is declared outside of any functions and the while loop is the only thing using it, it does not need to be defined as a global variable.

## Revised Program

```
def playAgain():
    b = input('Do you want to play again? y/n')
    if b == ('y'):
        return True
    else:
        print('Goodbye!')
        time.sleep(1)
        sys.exit()

import random
import time
import sys

shots = 0


while shots <=5:
    chanceofDeath =random.randint(1,6)
    input('press enter to play Russian roulette.')
    if chanceofDeath ==1:
        shots = shots + 1
        print (shots)
        print('You died.')
        time.sleep(1)

        if playAgain():
            shots = 0

    else:
        shots = shots + 1
        print (shots)
        print ('click')

    if shots == 5:
        print('You won without dying!')
        time.sleep(1)

        if playAgain():
            shots = 0
```

---

Also I am unsure of what you wanted your code to do with the following:

```
def startGame():
    startGame()
```

---

Hope this helps